# Animating scale attribute in react-native-svg

Tags: react-native, svg, react-animated, react-native-svg

I am trying to animate a rectangle made using `react-native-svg` by this code:

```
function TestAnimation() {
  const animatedScaleValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;
  const AnimatedRect = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Rect);

  const startAnimation = () => {
    Animated.timing(animatedScaleValue, {
      toValue: 2,
      duration: 2000,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Svg height={400} width={400}>
        <AnimatedRect
          x={50}
          y={50}
          width={50}
          height={100}
          scale={animatedScaleValue}
        />
      </Svg>
      <Button title="start animation" onPress={startAnimation} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

but its not working, the svg remains the same.

I also tried to animate `height` instead `scale` and its working fine.

what could be the reason behind it and possible workarounds.